# how to set the navigationUrl of a hyperlinkField in SPGridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to get all site-collections under the root site and display them using SPGridView. In the SPGridView I am using HyperlinkField to display the name, url and created for each site.
My problem is that I cannot attach the url of the site to HyperlinkField. Any idea how this can be done in code?

```
[ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
public class SPGridViewDemo : WebPart
{
    private SPGridView grid;
    private ObjectDataSource gridDS;

    public DataTable SelectData()
    {
        DataTable dataSource = new DataTable();

        dataSource.Columns.Add("Name");
        dataSource.Columns.Add("Created");
        dataSource.Columns.Add("Url");

        SPWebApplication webApplication = SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication;
        SPSiteCollection siteCollections = webApplication.Sites;
        SPSite currentSite = SPContext.Current.Site;

        foreach (SPSite siteCollection in siteCollections)
            {
                dataSource.Rows.Add(siteCollection.RootWeb.Title, siteCollection.RootWeb.Created, siteCollection.RootWeb.Url);
            }

        return dataSource;
    }


    protected sealed override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        BoundField column = new BoundField();
        HyperLinkField hyplink = new HyperLinkField();

        hyplink.DataTextField = "Name";
        hyplink.NavigateUrl = "Url";
        hyplink.SortExpression = "Name";
        hyplink.HeaderText = "Workspaces";
        grid.Columns.Add(hyplink);

        column = new BoundField();
        column.DataField = "Created";
        column.SortExpression = "Created";
        column.HeaderText = "Created";
        grid.Columns.Add(column);

        column = new BoundField();
        column.DataField = "Url";
        column.SortExpression = "Url";
        column.HeaderText = "Url";
        grid.Columns.Add(column);

        grid.Sort("Name",System.Web.UI.WebControls.SortDirection.Descending); 
        grid.DataBind();

        base.Render(writer);
    }

    protected sealed override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        const string gridId = "grid";
        const string dataSourceId = "gridDS";

        gridDS = new ObjectDataSource();
        gridDS.ID = dataSourceId;
        gridDS.SelectMethod = "SelectData";
        gridDS.TypeName = this.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName;
        gridDS.ObjectCreating += new ObjectDataSourceObjectEventHandler(gridDS_ObjectCreating);
        this.Controls.Add(gridDS);

        grid = new SPGridView();
        grid.ID = gridId;
        grid.DataSourceID = gridDS.ID;
        grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        // Paging
        grid.AllowPaging = true;
        grid.PageSize = 5;

        // Sorting
        grid.AllowSorting = true;

        this.Controls.Add(grid);

        SPGridViewPager pager = new SPGridViewPager();
        pager.GridViewId = grid.ID;

        this.Controls.Add(pager);
    }

    private void gridDS_ObjectCreating(object sender, ObjectDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ObjectInstance = this;
    }
```

Comment: Your code is missing crucial information: Where does `Url` come from? Are you receiving an error? Is `.NavigateUrl` simply empty when doing it your way? What happens when you set `.NavigateUrl` to a random URL like google.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [HyperLinkField.DataNavigateUrlFields Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.datanavigateurlfields%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) instead:

```
HyperLinkField hyplink = new HyperLinkField();

hyplink.DataTextField = "Name";
hyplink.DataNavigateUrlFields = new string[] { "Url" };
hyplink.SortExpression = "Name";
hyplink.HeaderText = "Workspaces";
grid.Columns.Add(hyplink);
```

The [HyperLinkField.NavigateUrl Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.navigateurl%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) is used to render static urls:

> Use the NavigateUrl property to specify the URL to navigate to when a hyperlink in a HyperLinkField object is clicked. When this property is set, each hyperlink shares the same navigation URL.

Comment: Hi Stefan. Thanks for your reply. It is true what you say. I used it like this: DataNavigateUrlFields = new[] {"Url"},
             DataNavigateUrlFormatString = "{0}",

Comment: According to the docu `DataNavigateUrlFormatString` is not required for basic display.